# Trigger dropdown 'onChange' programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am populating a dropdown on page load using some business logic and one of the values MAY (or may not) be selected, depending on the if conditions.

I am not able to:

> 1. Find which value is selected after load, if any
> 2. trigger the 'onChange' function for that dropdown using that selected value, if any value was selected

A sample code I am trying is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/1203/

```
<div id="outerDiv">

<select id="myDropdown" class="check">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
<option value="four">four</option>
</select>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {

    //call on load
    someFunction();

     $(document).on('change', '#myDropdown', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('selected_val', $(this).val());
       alert($(this).val());

    });

    function someFunction(){
    var mycondition = "true";
    //run busines slogic
    var htmlVar = "";
    if(mycondition == 'true'){

    htmlVar = '<select id="myDropdown" class="check">'+
        '<option value="one">one</option>'+
        '<option value="two">two</option>'+
        '<option selected = "selected" value="three">three</option>'+
        '<option value="four">four</option>'+
        '</select>';
    }

    $("#outerDiv").empty();
    $("#outerDiv").append(htmlVar);

    }
});
```

The function should fire itself for the value 'three' (value can change based on run time conditions). So basically, on page load, 'three' should be alerted in this example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the change event manually at page load:

```
$("#myDropdown").change();
```

This will need to happen *after* `someFunction()` or `#myDropdown` won't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** No need to use `empty()` then `.append()` you can directly use `html()`

**2nd:** The change event won't run because the element not presents to the DOM yet so you need to check the `html()` is finished .. you'll need to use `$.when().then()`

**3rd** to trigger the event you can use `.change()` *like @Daniel said* .. after the `change()` event not before it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // change event
  $(document).on('change', '#myDropdown', function() {
    //localStorage.setItem('selected_val', $(this).val());
    alert($(this).val());
  });
  
  //call on load
  $.when(someFunction()).then(function(){
    $('#myDropdown').change();
  });
});

// functions
function someFunction(){
  var mycondition = "true";
  //run busines slogic
  var htmlVar = "";
  if(mycondition == 'true'){

  htmlVar = '<select id="myDropdown" class="check">'+
  '<option value="one">one</option>'+
  '<option value="two">two</option>'+
  '<option selected = "selected" value="three">three</option>'+
  '<option value="four">four</option>'+
  '</select>';
  }

  $("#outerDiv").html(htmlVar);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="outerDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

`$(document).ready(function () {
   someFunction();
    dropDownChange($('#myDropdown'));
     $(document).on('change', '#myDropdown', function() {
        dropDownChange($(this));
     });
    function dropDownChange(e){
        localStorage.setItem('selected_val', e.val());
       alert(e.val());
    };
    function someFunction(){
    var mycondition = true;
    var htmlVar = "";
    if(mycondition){
    htmlVar = '<select id="myDropdown" class="check">'+
        '<option value="one">one</option>'+
        '<option value="two">two</option>'+
        '<option selected = "selected" value="three">three</option>'+
        '<option value="four">four</option>'+
        '</select>';
    }
    $("#outerDiv").html(htmlVar);
    };
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/v7QWd/1207/